# nginx: Node.js reverse proxy: problems with CNI of SSL certs on multiple domains

Tags: nginx, ssl, node.js

I'm a web developer, so be patient.

I have 3 personal domains hosted on my VPS with nginx used as web server for proxying incoming https requests to 3 different Node.js sites. SSL certs work well on all browsers both on nginx and Node.js `https` module. Browsers are ok with that.

The problem is when I run `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect gabrieleromanato.io:443` I got `unable to verify the first certificate` and when I run `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect gabrieleromanato.name:443` I got the same error because the CN part shows gabrieleromanato.io instead of gabrieleromanato.name. gabrieleromanato.io has been set as `default_server`. I couldn't get it to work otherwise.

I've also tried to use `proxy_ssl_certificate`and `proxy_ssl_certificate_key` as shown  [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/nginx-https-upstreams/) but running `nginx -t` returns an error which tells that such directives are unknown. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.5 and nginx 1.4.6.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: openssl `s_client` by default doesn't send SNI (Server Name Indication) which is needed for a TLS server that uses multiple certs; **add `-servername`** with the same hostname as `-connect` (but no port). Also older non-RedHat versions of OpenSSL don't default truststore correctly: https://superuser.com/questions/903247/ssl-root-ca-certificate-is-not-recognized-although-present-in-the-trust-store/

Answer (score 1):

You use Comodo certificates, I checked them via SSL Labs:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=gabrieleromanato.io&latest

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=gabrieleromanato.name&latest

The problem is you didn't bundle the certificate with the ca-bundle as per the instructions:

https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1091/37/certificate-installation--nginx

Now, your server is just sending one certificate, which is incomplete as we need the full chain.

Beyond this problem, you also have general issues mainly related to security. You shouldn't use SSL3.0 anymore and disable the weak DH ciphers. Performance wise, you should look into session resumption/cache and OCSP stapling.